# TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment when trying to run thru variables to write to them

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, variables, praw

So I have this code:

```
answeariteration = 0
while answeariteration < int(numberofanswears):
    thread = reddbot.submission(url = str(submissionurl))
    globals()["answear" + str(answeariteration)] = "test"

    answear = thread.comments[answeariteration]

    "answear" [answeariteration] = str(answear)
    answeariteration += 1
```

and when I run it i get:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

I make some variables with the names like answear0, answear1, etc. Then I need to write to replace the test text in these variables with a string:

```
"answear" [answeariteration] = str(answear)
```

It won't let me cycle thru every variable name.

Comment: store "answear" in a variable

Comment: Are answears different from normal answers?

Comment: @PavanKumarTS It spits out annother error: TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment . And I already tried that out. I was trying to resolve this for 3 hours

Comment: `"answear" [answeariteration] = str(answear)` doesn't make sense. Strings are immutable in Python.

Comment: @gilch before I store the "answear_text" in answear0, 1, etc. I store them temporarely in answear

Comment: @gilch how do I resolve that? I just need a way to write to a lot of variables different stuff, in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant the line

```
"answear" [answeariteration] = str(answear)
```

to be

```
globals()["answear"+str(answeariteration)] = str(answear)
```

But this is not a good way to do it. Instead of manipulation of variable names, you can use a dict. Maybe something like this:

```
answer = {}

answer_iteration = 0
while answer_iteration < int(numberofanswers):
    thread = reddbot.submission(url=str(submissionurl))
    answer[answer_iteration] = str(thread.comments[answer_iteration])
    answer_iteration += 1
```

And you can use a `for` loop instead of `while`.

```
answer = {}

for answer_iteration in range(numberofanswers):
    thread = reddbot.submission(url=str(submissionurl))
    answer[answer_iteration] = str(thread.comments[answer_iteration])
```

And you probably don't need to do the thread every loop, although I'm guessing about some things at this point.

```
answer = {}
thread = reddbot.submission(url=str(submissionurl))
for answer_iteration, comment in enumerate(thread.comments):
    answer[answer_iteration] = str(comment)
```

And now this is simple enough to be a comprehension

```
thread = reddbot.submission(url=str(submissionurl))
answer = {i: str(comment) for i, comment in enumerate(thread.comments)}
```

Which could maybe be simplified to just

```
thread = reddbot.submission(url=str(submissionurl))
answer = dict(enumerate(thread.comments))
```

if the comments were already strings. Not sure.

And that could maybe be simplified to

```
thread = reddbot.submission(url=str(submissionurl))
answer = list(thread.comments)
```

or even

```
answer = list(reddbot.submission(url=str(submissionurl)).comments)
```

Since we were using numerical keys, starting from 0.

In these cases, instead of using `answer0`, `answer1`, `answer2`, etc, you can use `answer[0]`, `answer[1]`, `answer[2]`, etc.